# TypeError: Cannot read property React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    export default function Detail(props){

    return(
        <Modal  {...props}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton style={{ backgroundColor: '#6595FC', color:'white' }}>
                <Modal.Title style={{ wordBreak: 'break-all' }}>
                    {props.jobname} Details
                </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        {props.detailData.detailData ? props.detailData.detailData[0].WORKFLOW_NAME : ''}
                        {props.detailData.detailData ? props.detailData.detailData[0].SQL_ID : ''} 
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="primary" style={{ backgroundColor: '#6595FC' }}>Restart</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
}
```

When there is data it works perfectly fine but when there is no data, it gives me the error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'WORKFLOW_NAME' of undefined**

props.detailData.detailData ? props.detailData.detailData[0].WORKFLOW_NAME : ' ' isnt this suppose to work like a null & empty check?

Comment: You've established that `detailData` is defined but not that `[0]` is defined. If `detailData` is an empty array, then that'd cause this error, e.g. `[][0].WORKFLOW_NAME` reproduces the error. Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David's answer is perfect. But you also can do this:

```
props.detailData?.detailData[0]?.WORKFLOW_NAME || ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only checking if `props.detailData.detailData` itself is "truthy" (it exists).  An empty array exists and passes this check, but it has no element at position `0` so the attempt to dereference that element will result in an error.

You can also add a length check:

```
(props.detailData.detailData && props.detailData.detailData.length > 0) ? props.detailData.detailData[0].WORKFLOW_NAME : ''
```

If you need to defend against other kinds of bad data you might also add [an `isArray()` check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), but that may be overkill.